# SCP from Windows using the colon-inclusive full path

Tags: windows, command-line, scp

I'm trying to run SCP on my Windows box through a batch file.

I want to do something like:

```
scp "C:\myfile.txt" user@host:path
```

Of course scp thinks that "C" is my source host and "\myfile.txt" is my source path.  I can't seem to find a way to escape the colon.

These don't work:

```
scp "C\:\myfile.txt" user@host:path
scp "C::\myfile.txt" user@host:path
scp "C^:\myfile.txt" user@host:path
```

SCP man pages suggest that using the "absolute or relative pathname" should eliminate this problem but I'm using the absolute pathname and this is still an issue.  They likely mean it eliminates the problem on *nix where absolute and relative pathnames start with "/" or ".".

Suggestions (aside from throwing my Windows box off the freaking roof)?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`pscp`](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html), though. The PuTTY author seems to put a lot more effort into making sure that his programs run on Windows while many native Unix software gets ported very poorly, as you note.

Answer (score 2):

If your working dir is in C: you should be able to specify `\myfile.txt`. If you are using [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) you could try `\c\myfile.txt`.  If you are using [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) then `/cygdrive/c/myfile.txt` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try
    `scp "/c/myfile.txt" user@host:path`

Comment: Welcome to [su]! Thanks for your contribution but your answer adds nothing to [krock's answer](http://superuser.com/a/291827/300383) from five years ago. Having multiple answers that say the same thing just clutters up the page.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: If you look closely, you'll see that Darien is suggesting a variation that's slightly different from any of the ones that krock listed.  This might have been better handled as a comment (since Darien ***does*** have commenting privileges), but "your answer adds nothing" seems a little harsh.

Comment: @G-Man Perhaps I was over-hasty. However, this answer would be greatly improved by an explanation of how it differs from the superficially near-identical prior answer and in what circumstances this answer can be expected to work.